# Image tag with text in HTML

Tags: html, image, text

I have a image 'm1' and a text 'Sample text'. i need to display the image and text as,

m1 Sample text. This text should be displayed in such a way that it is in center axis to the image. There should be spacing between image and text. how can i get this using HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify `vertical-align: middle` in the image's CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use align attribute inside **img** tag. For example:

```
<img src="someimgurl" align="absmiddle">
```

Spacing between image and text you can control with **CSS Margin**:

```
<img src="someimgurl" align="absmiddle" style="margin-right:5px">
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry its pretty simple. using vertical-align: middle we can achieve this. Sorry to asking such a simple question here.

Comment: "all things are difficult before they are easy" keep visiting stack and learn daily :)